# RavenDB - Load Balance and Replication

Tags: load-balancing, replication, ravendb

I'm using `RavenDB` with following setting:

```
FailoverBehavior = FailoverBehavior.ReadFromAllServers |
                   FailoverBehavior.AllowReadsFromSecondariesAndWritesToSecondaries
```

I'm also using two `RavenDB` servers which replicates each other.

Unfortunately I have following problem:

When document is written to PRIMARY raven database, but `Load Balancing` tries to read that document from other raven database, document is not there yet, because of Replication lag.

Is there anyway to tell `RavenDB` to wait until document is fully replicated before it's accessible from any boxes? Something similar to `WaitForNonStaleResults` for indexes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using write assurances, see : https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/server/scaling-out/replication/write-assurance